# Do the second differences of the fifth powers count the sphere packing of a polyhedron?

Tags: sequences-and-series, volume, cubics, polyhedra, finite-differences

If the third powers count the packing of a cube:
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343..]

And the first differences of the fourth powers form a cubic sequence that counts a packing of a rhombic dodecahedron (see picture):
[15, 65, 175, 369, 671, 1105, 1695..].

[Rhombic dodecahedral numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I7dO.png)

https://oeis.org/A005917

Do the second differences of the fifth powers have any associated polyhedra with a packing counted as: [30, 180, 570, 1320, 2550, 4380, 6930..]?

What about the cubic differences of the nth powers?

Comment: As @Wood said, the original post implied that the first differences of the fourth powers counted the volume of a rhombic dodecahedron. So I changed "counts the volumes of" to "counts a packing of".

Answer (score 1):

That sequence doesn't count the volume of the [rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron). The volume is given by $\frac{16\sqrt{3}}{9}a^3$. But from the image you linked it does seem to count some kind of sphere packing. The $n^4-(n-1)^4$ seems to come from the fact that some vertices have $4$ edges connected to it which can be used to generate the whole polyhedron with the parametric equation:

$$
\vec{p}(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4) = t_1\vec{e_1} + t_2\vec{e_2} + t_3\vec{e_3} + t_4\vec{e_4} 
$$

where the $\vec{e_k}$'s are the vectors corresponding to the edges and $0\le t_k \le 1$. Each edge multiplies the total number of spheres by $n$, except that the $4$th time you do this, you're counting twice a total of $(n-1)^4$ spheres.

Another way to think of this is by using the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). We start by splitting the rhombic dodecahedron into $4$ [triagonal trapezohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_trapezohedron), each having $n^3$ spheres, ignoring the overlap on the faces. To take this overlap into account, we must remove $6\times 4-12 = 12$ faces, with a "total" of $12 n^2$ spheres, but now we counted the spheres on some edges twice. There are $4$ such edges that we must add back, but if we add $4n$ spheres now it's the center sphere that was counted twice and we must remove. Adding it all up gives $4 n^3 - 6 n^2 + 4 n - 1 = n^4-(n-1)^4$.

Can we do something similar for another polyhedron and get [the second differences of the fifth powers](https://oeis.org/A068236)? I suspect not, otherwise I think this result would be noteworthy enough to show up on some quick searches (specially on the OEIS page). The most obvious generalization would come with the [rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron), because it can be split into $20$ trigonal trapezohedra and it can be generated by a similar parametric equation:

$$
\vec{p}(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5) = t_1\vec{e_1} + t_2\vec{e_2} + t_3\vec{e_3} + t_4\vec{e_4} + t_5\vec{e_5} 
$$

The second difference of the fifth power is $20 n^3 - 60 n^2 + 70 n - 30$, which looks promising because of the $20n^3$, but the next term should have been $-(6\times 20-30)n^2 = -90n^2$ to correspond with the $90$ faces that were counted twice. So this doesn't seem to work. The first method (using the parametric equation) also doesn't work because the overlap begins with $n^4$, and not $n^5$.